# The XAML Designer has exited unexpectedly. (Exit code: e0434352)

Tags: c#, wpf

Xaml Designer keeps crashing, more info:

Error

```
The XAML Designer has exited unexpectedly. (Exit code: e0434352)
```

Visual Studio Specs:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.1.4
```

Windows Specs:

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎10/‎7/‎2021
OS build    22000.613
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.613.0
```

WpfSurface Memory Dump File:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/34f7d58db430ab8e4f28e599664ca4e420220416155752/bd9123

Answer (score 7):

removed

```
<!--<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>-->
```

from csproj

fixed the problem

Comment: I still need win-x64 in Release, so I placed this in a PropertyGroup with a Condition, so that I can design when in Debug in VS.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with:
Win 10
VS Pro 2022 17.1.6

Additionally:
CommunityToolkit.mvvm (7.1.2)
Microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client (6.0.4)

Even a completely new, empty WPF window will not show in the designer.
All usual actions like clean recompiling, removing all temporary and generated files, restarting the VS, etc. didn't help to address the problem.

Comment: My project target version was NET 6.0, but now i downgraded to .NET Core 3.1. Now works fine, may you should this.

Comment: Can confirm this is still a problem (although I get error code 80008089, which I can find NOTHING about on a google search). VS Pro 22 17.4.4. A clean install on another box runs things just fine - just my development install seems fubarred. @BedirhanSAMSA; we should not have to back down - 6 is the latest long term support, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem
To solve the problem, try to set the IsDesignTimeCreatable to False in the design DataContext

```
 d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vms:DashboardViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}
```