# XAML (Exit code: e0434352) - Works when \bin deleted, fails again after rebuild

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml

Using Visual Studio Preview 2022. Project: https://github.com/dmenne/FS2020Control.

The project compiles and runs without error, but using the XAML Designer gives:

`The XAML Designer has exited unexpectedly. (Exit code: e0434352)`

None of the suggestions displayed with the error message works. Following several older threads on `e0434352`, I deleted the `\bin` folder. After that, I can use the designer until I do a rebuild - then the error is back. So I have to re-delete the folder every time I use the Designer.

Why does the presence of a \bin folder affect the Designer?

See also https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2780

Comment: Hi, according to [The XAML Designer has exited unexpectedly. (Exit code: e0434352)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71895397/the-xaml-designer-has-exited-unexpectedly-exit-code-e0434352) , you can try to replace the .net version first

Comment: The suggestion was to downgrade to .NET 3.1 which was not what I wanted. It still remains unclear why the content of the /bin folder influences the designer. Microsoft's suggestion in MAUI is to use live preview.

Comment: So does the live preview solve your issue?

Comment: Also have this exact error on our own inhouse project. Started after an update of VS2022 last week.
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Edit your App.config and remove the startup section after changing your targeted framework..

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       :
```

To:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     :
```

These action resolve the problem for me.